# Create a game configuration/options (config.cfg) file in Python

Tags: python, pygame, config, settings

I am now relatively experienced in Python and Pygame for creating a few basic 2D graphical games. Now I want to be able to create a configuration file (config.cfg) so that I can permanently store settings and configurations for the game for things like window width and height and FPS count. The file should read vertically e.g.

```
FPS = 30
WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720
etc.
```

Obviously I need to be able to read (and create) this file from my game and also edit the values without touching the text labels. I have not touched on this stuff before although I have worked with using text files in Python  so I need as much guidance as possible please.     I am using Python 3.3 with Pygame 1.9 on Windows 8 Pro x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**myConfig.cfg:**

```
[info]

Width = 100

Height = 200

Name = My Game
```

**Parsing** in python:

```
import ConfigParser

configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
configFilePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'myConfig.cfg')
configParser.read(configFilePath)
gameName = configParser.get("info","Name")
gameWidth  = configParser.get("info","Width")
gameHeight = configParser.get("info","Height")

configParser.set('info', 'Name', 'newName')
config.write(configFilePath)
```

**Explanation:**

First we crate an instance of `ConfigParser` then we are telling the instance where the `.cfg` file is located, after just it's just reading.
The second part we handle the writing.

**More information:**

Config Parser from [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)

If you are looking for something more flexible try [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) and [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/)

Comment: Two small comments: In Python 3 `ConfigParser` was renamed to `configparser` and he wants to write config files too, otherwise good Answer.

Comment: @Mailerdaimon Writing was added(it was on edit) about Python 3, you are right :)

Comment: Hi, just to clarify... will the values in gameName, gameWidth & gameHeight end up as being 'My Game', 100 and 200 respectively after running that script??? And I don't get the writing bit...

Comment: The first part will get values from the file `gameName` will be `My Game` , `gameWidth ` will be  `100`, the second part is an example how you can change the value of `Name` in the file to `newName`

Comment: OK thanks a lot for clarifying that. I will try this out later and hopefully report back.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the [configparser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.htm) (ConfigParser for < Python 3) module.

Example from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.htm) (this uses Python 2.* Syntax, you have to use `configparser`):

Read

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('example.cfg')

a_float = config.getfloat('Section1', 'a_float')
an_int = config.getint('Section1', 'an_int')
print a_float + an_int

if config.getboolean('Section1', 'a_bool'):
    print config.get('Section1', 'foo')
```

Write

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()

config.add_section('Section1')
config.set('Section1', 'an_int', '15')
config.set('Section1', 'a_bool', 'true')
config.set('Section1', 'a_float', '3.1415')
config.set('Section1', 'baz', 'fun')
config.set('Section1', 'bar', 'Python')
config.set('Section1', 'foo', '%(bar)s is %(baz)s!')

with open('example.cfg', 'wb') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

Answer (score 2):

File handling is pretty simple in python. And, for your purpose I would recommend using `json`.

You could code something like

```
import os
import json

# Default settings
default_settings = {'FPS': 30,
                    'WINDOW_HEIGHT': 720,
                    'WINDOWS_WIDTH': 1280
                    }
handle_settings(default_settings)

def handle_settings(settings):
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'config.cfg')):
        with open('config.cfg', 'r') as settings_file:
            settings = json.load(settings_file) # load from file
    else:
        with open('config.cfg', 'w') as settings_file:
            json.dump(settings, settings_file)  # write to file

# Changed settings as per user config
handle_settings(changed_settings)
```